# Dell XPS can't boot from USB. TPM maybe?

Tags: boot, dell-xps, tpm

On my Dell XPS 9310 (factory default) I get
`set_second_stage{} failed invalid parameter something has seriously gone wrong shim_init{} failed: invalid parameter`

TPM 2.0 seems to be turned on. I try to boot Clonezilla from an USB device. I've used dd to put the ISO on the USB device.

Edit: I noticed that it only didn't work when booting from my external SSD "Western Digital My Passport Go 1TB"

Comment: Is Secure Boot On or Off?  It may need to be Off for this. It is not likely a TPM issue.

Comment: TPM doesn't block or change boot settings. It supports functions an installed OS MAY use, not what can and cannot boot your device.

Comment: Secure Boot seems to be off in the default. I edited my initial post because I noticed this only happened with the WD "My Passport Go" SSD.

Comment: Try to get a Dell Recovery USB Key and try to boot with that. This will help you narrow down issues.

Comment: Does the computer boot normally, without a USB? What is loaded on the USB that you are trying to boot? Based on the message you're giving, it sounds to me like the system IS booting to the USB, but the image is incorrect, faulty, or does not support your system. Basically, the error message you've presented is NOT a BIOS or system firmware message, but a message from an OS loader, so the problem is likely NOT the system's boot configuration, but the configuration of the software or device you are booting to.